# How to combine and nest related JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I have two json files that I would like to combine into a single json object that can be read on my front end.

**fragments.json**

```
[
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "John Smith is nice",
      "reports": "1,2",
      "entities": 1,
    }
]
```

**entities.json**

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "fragments": 2,
      "name": "John SMITH",
      "dateOfBirth": "4/24/1967",
    }
]
```

**Desired Result.json**

I want to show all the entities that are connected to any given fragment.

```
[
    {
       "id":2,
       "title":"John Smith is nice",
       "reports":"1,2",
       "entities":{
          "id":1,
          "fragments":2,
          "name":"John SMITH",
          "dateOfBirth":"4/24/1967"
       }
    }
 ]
```

Here's my code so far:

```
router.get('/sprint-3/:prototype/report/:reportId', function (req, res) {

    const slug = +req.params.reportId
    const report = reports.find(({ id }) => id === slug);

    const reportFragments = fragments.filter(({ reports }) => reports.includes(report.id) );

    reportFragments.forEach(fragment => {
        const reportEntities = entities.filter(({ fragments }) => fragments === fragment.id );
        reportFragments.push(reportEntities);
        console.log('New', reportFragments)
    });


    res.render("sprint-3/prototype-1/report", { report: report, fragments: reportFragments });
});
```

I've been looking at .push as a way of doing this, but currently it appends the entities to the end of the reportFragments rather than nesting inside each of them.

Comment: unclear what connects the json records

Comment: The id from entities.json matches the entities field in fragments.json

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce like so

```js
const reportFragments = [{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "John Smith is nice",
  "reports": "1,2",
  "entities": 1,
}]

const entities = [{
  "id": 1,
  "fragments": 2,
  "name": "John SMITH",
  "dateOfBirth": "4/24/1967",
}]

const merged = reportFragments.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const match = entities.filter(ent => ent.fragments === curr.id);
  return [...acc, ({
    id: curr.id,
    title: curr.title,
    reports: curr.reports,
    ...{
      entities: match
    }
  })]
}, [])

console.log(merged)
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. That's working brilliantly. Can I use that method to connect a single entity to multiple fragments? E.g. 

const entities = [{
  "id": 1,
  "fragments": [1,2],
}]

Doesn't seem to work when I try it. Thanks again!

Comment: You can definitely extend it to do so. By doing something like `ent.fragments.includes(curr.id)`